# SVG to PNG, why arrow heads are not converting ?

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, png

I am working on a project where i am creating the SVG elements on the fly. When i tried to convert the svg to image, no idea why arrow heads are not picked up. Adding the fiddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ddjaq32j/

```
var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.querySelector('svg'));

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        var img = new Image();
        var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            document.querySelector('#png-container').innerHTML = '<img src="'+png+'"/>';
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
        };
        img.src = url;
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for, both SVG and img are showing the same image, right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ddjaq32j/embedded/result/

Comment: In the image, arrow heads are not showing..

Comment: What is your browser version?

Comment: im testing on Firefox ver 41.0

Comment: Looks like a bug in FF.  You should report it.

Comment: It's a [known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=841920), please don't report it again.

Comment: thanks guys .. i tried using CANVG plugin.. i am able to get the arrow head.. but its kind of miss placed .. any idea how to fix ?

Comment: adding the fiddle link 

http://jsfiddle.net/L3hondLn/143/